# how to split a string on certain conditions

Tags: java

I have a following string

> books/eh/grayL88/WilliamsMC88:::M. Howard Williams::P. A. Massey::Jim A. Crammond:::Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.

How should i use or in other words what to use so that at last i may get

> M. Howard Williams --  Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.
>
> P. A. Massey    --     Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.
>
> Jim A. Crammond  --    Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.

Thanks

Comment: Well developer i have tried         line.split("::\\s*"); but its not working

Comment: @user1758521. You could use `":::?"` for your regex. the last `:?` means `0 or 1` `:`. That will match `::` and `:::`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1st Way:

- You can first split your string on the basis of `:::`. This will give you an array of length 3. You would be interested in the `2nd` and the `3rd` element of your array.
- Then split the `2nd element` of your array on `::`. This will give you an array containing `each name`.
- Iterate over the `2nd array` and print each name with the `3rd element` of your first array.

  ```
  String str = "books/eh/grayL88/WilliamsMC88:::M. Howard Williams::" + 
               "P. A. Massey::Jim A. Crammond:::Benchmarking Prolog for " + 
               "Database Applications.";

  String[] arr = str.split(":::");
  String[] innerArr = arr[1].split("::");

  for (String name: innerArr) {
      System.out.println(name + " -- " + arr[2]);
  }
  ```

**OUTPUT**: -

> M. Howard Williams -- Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.
>   P. A. Massey -- Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications. 
>   Jim A.Crammond -- Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.

---

### 2nd Way:

Or, you can split on `:::?`. This will split on `::` or `:::`, that will get each individual elements in your first array only (Will work only for `3` names. For more, you should better use the first one)

```
    String[] arr = str.split(":::?");

    System.out.println(arr[1] + " - " + arr[4]);
    System.out.println(arr[2] + " - " + arr[4]);
    System.out.println(arr[3] + " - " + arr[4]);
```

**OUTPUT**: -

> M. Howard Williams - Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.
> P.
>   A. Massey - Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications. 
> Jim A.
>   Crammond - Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.

Comment: +1 for the first approach. The second approach only works if there are always three authors, or by adding additional logic. The first one actually implements the syntax of the string, so it is the better solution in my opinion.

Comment: @brimborium. Yeah that's right. Keeping in mind that it would work only for 3 names, only I posted the 1st solution first. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
String s = "books/eh/grayL88/WilliamsMC88:::M. Howard Williams::P. A. Massey::Jim A. Crammond:::Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.";

String split[] = s.split(":::");
String end = split[split.length - 1];

String[] names = split[1].split("::");

for (String name : names)
    System.out.println(name + " -- " + end);
```

---

Output:

> M. Howard Williams -- Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.
>   P. A. Massey -- Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.
>   Jim A. Crammond -- Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:
(Pseudo code...)

```
myString.remove("(.*/)+[^:]*:{3}");
lastString = myString.split(":::").takeLast();
array names = myString.split("([^:]*)+");
result = "";

for (i=0;i<name.size();result+=names[i++]+" -- "+lastString+"\n");

// do whatever with "result"...
```

No freebies, not ever...

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringTokenizer. For example:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, "://");
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
   String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
   // ... and do whatever you like with the token
}
```

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is now deprecated - you should use the `split` method of strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "books/eh/grayL88/WilliamsMC88:::M. Howard Williams::P. A. Massey::" +
        "Jim A. Crammond:::Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.";
        String split[]=str.split(":::");
        String names[] = split[1].split("::");
        String sentence = split[2];
        for(String name : names){
            System.out.println(name + " -- " +sentence);
        }
```

**Output :**

M. Howard Williams -- Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.
P. A. Massey -- Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.
Jim A. Crammond -- Benchmarking Prolog for Database Applications.